# Terraform AWS IAM: Why must policy documents be data?

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

In examples of https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document the `aws_iam_policy_document` is defined as `data` rather than `resource`. I am not familiar with Terraform, my understanding was that `data` was used when a resource already exists, to instruct Terraform to merely assume it's there rather than attempt to create it. However, if I am creating a new policy document, why would I use `data` rather than `resource`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data resources are for anything defined outside of Terraform, and you are absolutely correct in thinking that it's for when a resource already exists because...well, those are resources that were defined outside of TF.

The reason why the `aws_iam_policy_document` here is a data resource is because there's no actual `aws_iam_policy_document` resource that you can create (unlike a KMS secret, or S3 bucket).  Even when you use the AWS CLI to create a policy, you still have to pass an input of a policy file.  So I would think of the data resource here as a temp file of sorts (or a heredoc?).  You don't have to use the data resource and can use `jsonencode` and define the policy directly in your [`aws_iam_policy`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy) resource, but I think separating it just makes organization much simpler.

Comment: So is the `aws_iam_policy_document` here analogous to a Terraform local variable, in that it exists only while Terraform is figuring out how to interpret the config, and there is no corresponding resource being created?

Comment: I guess you can think of it that way, sure.  Although I wouldn't use a local var to store that info seeing as there's a perfectly good data resource at your disposal :D